# Write Canvas3D to file

Tags: java, 3d, java-3d

Hi i tried to adapt http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/3D/OffScreenTest.htm to a simple test which renders a color cube to file.

But my img.png contains only black color and the Program never quits.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;
import javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D;
import javax.media.j3d.ImageComponent;
import javax.media.j3d.ImageComponent2D;
import javax.media.j3d.Screen3D;

import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;

public class HelloJava3Db {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create canvas
        GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
        Canvas3D canvas3D = new Canvas3D(config, true);

        // create universe
        SimpleUniverse simpleU = new SimpleUniverse(canvas3D);
        simpleU.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();

        // create scene
        BranchGroup scene = new BranchGroup();
        scene.addChild(new ColorCube(0.4));
        scene.compile();
        simpleU.addBranchGraph(scene);

        // set off screen size
        Screen3D sOff = canvas3D.getScreen3D();
        sOff.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        sOff.setPhysicalScreenWidth(200);
        sOff.setPhysicalScreenHeight(200);

        // render to off screen
        BufferedImage bImage = new BufferedImage(200, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        ImageComponent2D buffer = new ImageComponent2D(ImageComponent.FORMAT_RGBA, bImage);
        buffer.setCapability(ImageComponent2D.ALLOW_IMAGE_READ);
        canvas3D.setOffScreenBuffer(buffer);
        canvas3D.renderOffScreenBuffer();
        canvas3D.waitForOffScreenRendering();

        // write to file
        File output = new File("img.png");
        try {
            ImageIO.write(bImage, "png", output);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(output.getAbsolutePath());

        simpleU.cleanup();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok two changes are needed to get it work:

1. my sOff.setPhysicalScreenWidth was too large
2. i had to use canvas3D.getOffScreenBuffer().getRenderedImage()

Working result:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;
import javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D;
import javax.media.j3d.ImageComponent;
import javax.media.j3d.ImageComponent2D;
import javax.media.j3d.Screen3D;

import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;

public class HelloJava3Db {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create canvas
        GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
        Canvas3D canvas3D = new Canvas3D(config, true);

        // create universe
        SimpleUniverse simpleU = new SimpleUniverse(canvas3D);
        simpleU.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();

        // create scene
        BranchGroup scene = new BranchGroup();
        scene.addChild(new ColorCube(0.4));
        scene.compile();
        simpleU.addBranchGraph(scene);

        // set off screen size
        Screen3D sOff = canvas3D.getScreen3D();
        sOff.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        sOff.setPhysicalScreenWidth(1);
        sOff.setPhysicalScreenHeight(1);

        // render to off screen
        BufferedImage bImage = new BufferedImage(200, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        ImageComponent2D buffer = new ImageComponent2D(ImageComponent.FORMAT_RGBA, bImage);
        buffer.setCapability(ImageComponent2D.ALLOW_IMAGE_READ);
        canvas3D.setOffScreenBuffer(buffer);
        canvas3D.renderOffScreenBuffer();
        canvas3D.waitForOffScreenRendering();

        // write to file
        File output = new File("img.png");
        try {
            ImageIO.write(canvas3D.getOffScreenBuffer().getRenderedImage(), "png", output);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(output.getAbsolutePath());

        simpleU.cleanup();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your findings. We'll check if the official examples in java3d-examples of offscreen rendering on Github work. I hope that you use the very latest version of Java3D, not the abandoned one provided by Oracle.

Comment: i was using 1.5.1, 1.6.1 seems to be in beta status?

Comment: There is no version called "1.6.1". There is a version called 1.6.0-pre12. The version 1.5.1 was the last version from Oracle /Sun Microsystems. The version 1.5.2 was provided by the community. The version 1.6.0 is the only maintained version (by the JogAmp community). The version 1.7 contains some breaking changes, some packages were renamed and a major contributor is going to add OpenGL-ES support. You can find some information about the installation here: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_Java3D http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Java3D_Overview

Comment: ok thanks then i'll check this "1.6.0-pre12" version out and go on with it

Comment: ok i found the 3 java3d files, but which of the jogamp jar files should i include in my project? the manual is not verry specific

Comment: ok found it "Unzipping the files" has some lists which jars to include

Comment: is there any way to get the sources of java3d 1.6?